# iPhone MessageFilterExtension not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

iPhone MessageFilterExtension not working properly.

New message marked as filter are not going to junk folder
But if we already have a message in conversion than the next filtered message is going to Junk folder.
Any one else facing this issue?

```swift
func handle(_ queryRequest: ILMessageFilterQueryRequest, context: ILMessageFilterExtensionContext, completion: @escaping (ILMessageFilterQueryResponse) -> Void) {

        let offlineAction:ILMessageFilterAction = .filter // just for testing
// hardcoded it to  filter But still first message is not going to junk second
// message goes to junk folder properly

        switch offlineAction {
        case .allow, .filter:
            let response = ILMessageFilterQueryResponse()
            response.action = offlineAction
            completion(response)
            break

        case .none:
                let response = ILMessageFilterQueryResponse()
                response.action = .allow
                completion(response)
            break
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in **iOS 12.x** and Fixed in **iOS 12.4**.

On **iOS 12.4** the same code is working as expected.